# Can't prevent browser from caching page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to prevent the browser to cache on form pages and block the user to return after submit.

**application_controller.rb**

```
protected

  def set_no_cache
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

**another_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :set_no_cache, only: [:new, :edit]
```

when add a `byebug` on the 'edit' action, for example, I see the headers correctly changed:

```
(byebug) headers
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", "Pragma"=>"no-cache", "Expires"=>"Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"}
```

But it doesn't work to me and I tried on Ubuntu for Chrome, Opera and Safari browsers.

Comment: You can try to add one more header - `response.headers['Last-Modified'] = CGI::rfc1123_date(Time.now)`

Comment: Hi @AlyoshaBrovikov, thank you for your answer and I tried it and doesn't work too...

Comment: Fillype, but what is your expectation for edit action? Can you share what exactly doesn't work for you (in logs, response details etc)?

Comment: After edit page, I'm redirected to 'show' page. Then I want to block the user tho come back to 'edit' page just clicking 'back'. I want to 'edit' page only be displayed if the user specifically click on the proper button to go to that.

Comment: I believe the caching is working for you. But it will do expected behavior for create action. Which means when you click back in browser after create new record you will get back to create page but fields will be empty because of cache is disabled. And if you have configured validations for you record it will prevent you to create duplicates of created record on previous step.  

In case of after edit action - when you back to previous step (pressing back in browser) you get to edit page with **updated** values (that ones which stored in DB), so it expected behavior.